# Money-Rails Gem - displaying humanised money with symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

Im trying to use Money-Rails with my Rails 4 app.

I have a participants model which has attributes as follows:

```
t.boolean  "costs"
t.integer  "participation_cost_pennies",  default: 0,     null: false
t.string   "participation_cost_currency", default: "GBP", null: false
```

Users can select their currency and that should override the default GBP setting.

Im my view, I have:

```
<% if @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:costs) == true %>
           <%=  @project.scope.try(:participant).try(humanized_money_with_symbol :@participation_cost_pennies) %>
```

When I try the above, the view shows up blank (no display of anything). When I try to inspect the element in the google browser, I can only see an empty span tag in which that code is set out (with nothing).

I previously tried the following, bit it displayed the price in pennies (as in $6 as 600 USD:

```
      <%=  "#{@project.scope.try(:participant).try(:participation_cost_pennies)} #{@project.scope.try(:participant).try(:participation_cost_currency)}" %>
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong? I'd like to display $4 instead of 400 cents/pennies.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`humanized_money_with_symbol` is a helper, so you use it in the form `humanized_money_with_symbol @money_object`.

In your case that means you would use it like so:

```
<%=  humanized_money_with_symbol @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:participation_cost_pennies) %>
```

all `try` does is call a method on the object you've chained and return nil if it doesn't exist. What you were doing was call `humanized_money_with_symbol` on a method named `:@participation_cost_pennies` on participant, which didn't exist, so `try` ended up returning `nil`

Comment: Hi Mario. thanks for the tip - I just tried that and it still doesn't work. Still renders blank on the view.

Comment: @user2860931 yeah sorry about that, I just noticed I left an '@' that shouldn't be there (you had it in your code). Check the edit